# App should not be installed more than 10 devices

Tags: android

I am developing an app for a limited number of users (10 users) in Android. When the app is installed on the 11th device, it should not be installed. How can I do that in Android?

Comment: whatever you are trying to do, keep in mind 2 points, [1] you can NOT prevent installation, so any action will be done after installation, [2] to determine how many devices have the app, you will need a centralized data (server side)

Comment: You cannot prevent installation, but you prevent usage of application, build licensing in your and force user to activate first then use, in this way you can track number of installations and prevent any non required user to use your app.

Comment: Why don't you just email the apk to the 10 users instead of publishing it to the play store just for 10 people?

Comment: @Eenvincible - obviously because they can forward the email to others

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this is by uploading your apk to a server then do the following:

- Create 10 user accounts with login credentials.
- Provide the login credentials to those 10 users.
- Once they are logged in, they can download the apk.

This should prevent unauthorized users from downloading your app.

This will also help you avoid all the checks you will have to do to make sure 10 people have installed your app - since you cannot really avoid an installation.

I hope this gives you an idea.

Comment: @user3853307 A possible issue with this approach is the user that downloads might share the APK file with others. If you trust the users then it could work out. The better solution is to have a centralized authentication process when the app runs (e.g. registration). You may still need to check each time the app runs to make sure someone didn't figure out a way to share after registration. It all comes down to trust.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent the installation ofcourse. But what you can do to handle this problem is that as the app is installed and started, hit a webservice made by you to check if there are more than 10 devices who have already installed this app, if the answer is yes, do not let the user go ahead but if 10 installations havnt been done, do an increment on your server and let the user pass by this step and use the App.

**EDIT**

As suggested by Saty, A registration process can also be useful in this case.